# IPython widgets not working on my github page

Tags: github, ipython, jupyter

I have a jupyter notebook that has widgets to include some interactivity in the code. Excerpting from this notebook:

```
cfd=widgets.IntSlider(min=1, max=99, step=1, value=50, description ="Slider")
widgets.interactive(main_function,cfd=cfd,gs=gs,ss=ss)
```

This shows the widget right below my code. When widget is interacted with, something happens that's displayed in the [Out] section.

I'm hosting this particular notebook on my github page, but widgets aren't displayed here, instead, it prints out:

```
interactive(children=(IntSlider(value=0, description='Slider'), ...)
```

How can I make IPython widgets work on github?

Answer (score 0):

Are you following the documentation on how to [embed widgets in static pages](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/embedding.html) ? Widgets needs JS libraries to work, and most likely your blog will need them as well as the widgets states.

You may want to also tell us which blog engine you are using, and how you make those notebook available on it in order for us to be able to diagnose the issue.

Comment: It's on my github page.

Comment: That's unfortunately an information already in your question, and that is of no help  to diagnose the problem. It's like saying that you are lost in San Francisco and are driving a car and want to get to lombard street, then when people ask you what you see around you you you reply "my car". It's technically correct but useless. At least link your page if you think it might help.

Comment: @Matt, I have similiar problem. It renders locally but not in [GitHub](https://github.com/dudung/python-jupyter-notebook/blob/main/widget/widget_hello_world.ipynb) nor in [nbviewer](https://nbviewer.org/github/dudung/python-jupyter-notebook/blob/main/widget/widget_hello_world.ipynb). I hope you can suggest a clue.